# Finding min of different counts in object

Tags: python, object, instances

Im trying to write a python method that looks at Rarity and counts the different types and then returns what the smallest count is but i keep getting: 'MagicCard' object is not subscriptable. Im also wanting to check which colors are associated with the least rare cards. Any help would be appreciated:

Here is where the Json can be obtained from for testing: http://mtgjson.com/json/DTK.json

Card Object:

```
class MagicCard(object):
    def __init__ (self, jsonCard):
        self.name=jsonCard["name"]

        if jsonCard.get("colors",""):
            self.colors=jsonCard["colors"]
        else:
            self.colors=None

        if jsonCard["rarity"]:
            self.rarity=jsonCard["rarity"]
        else:
            self.rarity=None

    def get_name(self):
        """Return the name of the card"""
        return self.name

    def get_colors(self):
        """Return the colors of the card"""
        return self.colors

    def get_rarity(self):
        """Return the rarity of the card"""
        return self.rarity
```

Card Deck Object:

```
class MagicCardSet(object):
    def __init__(self, DeckDict):
        self.cardlist = [MagicCard(eachCard) for eachCard in DeckDict["cards"]]

    def get_card_list(self):
        Card_name_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            Card_name_list.append(newCard.get_name())
        return(Card_name_list)

    def get_card_color(self):
        color_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            color_list.append(newCard.get_color())
        return(color_list)

    def get_card_rarity(self):
        rarity_list=[]
        for newCard in self.cardlist:
            rarity_list.append(newCard.get_rarity())
        return(rarity_list)

    def get_rarest_card(self):
        for eachCard in self.cardlist:
            if eachCard["rarity"]=="Uncommon":
                uncommon_counter = uncommon_counter + 1
            elif eachCard["rarity"]=="Common":
                common_counter=common_counter + 1
            elif eachCard["rarity"]=="Rare":
                rare_counter = rare_counter + 1
            elif eachCard["rarity"]=="Mythic Rare":
                mythic_rare_counter = mythic_rare_counter + 1
        return(mythic_rare_counter)
```

error:
[image]

Comment: This code is working, that is, I am not get a "not scriptable" error.  Maybe it would help to include a traceback, environment info, python version, etc.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] that shows us how you are using these classes. We have no idea what `jsonCard` or `DeckDict` look like. That error message makes sense to me: a `MagicCard` instance is a single card, not a collection of cards, so it's meaningless to try and index into it. OTOH, a `MagicCard` _does_ have a `.rarity` attribute, which you can access by doing `eachCard.rarity`.

Comment: How are you using these classes? Why are you using imgur!? Why you do not copy and paste it?

Comment: Im just doing a simple call of it to confirm the method works. ie. DTK_Set=MagicCardSet(DTK_information)
print(DTK_Set.get_card_list())

Comment: `if eachCard.get_rarity() == "Uncommon":

Answer (score 0):

The

```
for eachCard in self.cardlist
```

returns a MagicCard instance.  Call get_rarity() and get_name() and get_colors() on eachCard.

Also, to get the colors of the least rare (most common) cards:

```
unrare_colors = {}
for eachCard in self.cardlist:
    if eachCard.get_rarity() == "Common":
        for eachColor in eachCard.get_colors():
            unrare_colors[eachColor] = 1

for color in unrare_colors.keys():
    print(color)
```